# How is the application affected by the Sampling rate in AWS XRay?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

In the AWS Xray [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-concepts.html#xray-concepts-sampling) it is mentioned that the sdk applies sampling to the requests.
Now I want to implement distributed logging such that any request that comes in to the system can be tracked by using the `X-Amzn-Trace-Id` or some correlation ID, so that I can later execute a query to fetch all the logs for a given request (across all the microservices).
What is the best possible way to achieve it?
Also, if there is a SNS Topic where I am publishing my events and then a Queue is listening to the Topic, then how can I include that relation in the Xray Map?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common requirement in monitoring system, correlate traces, metrics and logs by keywords. In traces <-> logs case, it is by attaching trace id into logs. Please search topics like `OpenTelemetry Logging Instrumentation`

Regarding sampling, please check [this table](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/trace/sdk.md#recording-sampled-reaction-table). Basically, `not sampled` still generates trace context for correlating logs.